# How should I manage the path to unicorn pid file on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, unicorn

I am trying to do a rails 4+ ruby 2.0 depployment to a VPS on digitalocean. I am using the unicorn + capistrano stack.

In my local setup I have this file in as my config/unicorn.rb:

```
APP_ROOT =  File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)

working_directory APP_ROOT
pid "#{APP_ROOT}/tmp/unicorn.pid"
worker_processes 2

preload_app true

listen "/tmp/unicorn.sock"
timeout 30

stdout_path "#{APP_ROOT}/log/unicorn.log"
stderr_path "#{APP_ROOT}/log/unicorn.log"
```

Now my questions are:

1. Should I checking this file into git version control? OR
2. Should I have a separate unicorn.rb on my production server pointing the pid path to say, `/home/deploy/#{myapp}/tmp/unicorn.pid`?

I am confused about how to manage consistent paths, I guess. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to manage paths that differ between environments is via environment variables. Eg: `ENV['PIDS']`...

From the unicorn config file above, `pids` are always going to be dumped into `#{APP_ROOT}/tmp`, no matter what the environment...

Check out [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) and in particular the upstart export (if you're on Ubuntu) - ([Introducing Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html))